# How to change the location/path of unmanaged C libraries in VB.Net when using the P/Invoke layer?

Tags: vb.net, interop, pinvoke

Currently in our VB.Net windows application, C libraries are present under the 'bin' directory but we want to store it under aplication root directory where other forms and classes are present...How can we do this in Vb.Net 2008?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The P/Invoke layer uses the [rules that the LoadLibrary API function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684175(VS.85).aspx) uses in order to find the DLLs that you specify with the DllImport attribue.

That being said, you should look at the Remarks section of the LoadLibrary API function, as the [dllName parameter for the constructor of the DllImportAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute.dllimportattribute.aspx) is ultimately what is passed as the lpFileName parameter name for the LoadLibrary function.